# Printf outputting a bunch of zeros

Tags: c, printf

I'm new to C, so I apologize if the answer to this is painfully obvious! I mean to loop through two 2D arrays, passing correspondingly indexed members as arguments to my chineseRemainder routine, i.e. for each iteration, array1[i] and array2[i] should be passed to the routine, where i = i. I am expecting the output of a call to printf to be a certain set of numbers -- instead I am getting all zeros. Here is the main routine, where I call the CR function. **edit I gave xp and xq arbitrary int values, since they do not seem to be the problem, and giving them such values gives the same output.

```
int main(){

int xp, xq, p = 61, q = 3;
int i, j;

reverseInteger();

for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
        xq = 4;
        xp = 1;
        printf("%i\n", chineseRemainder(xq, xp, p, q));
            }
        }


return 0;

}
```

For troubleshooting's sake, I dumped the contents of xq and xp to make sure those assignments were going through: they are. The problem must be with the CR routine, because it is printing zero even when I pass any set of integers to it. So, here is that function, and its dependencies:

```
float power(int base, int exp) {

int i;
float result = 1;

if (exp == 0)
    result = 1;

else if (exp == 1)
    result = base;

else if(exp > 1){
    for (i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
        result *= base;
}

else
    result = 1/power(base, -exp);

return result;

}

float powerMod(int q, int e, int p){

float result;

result = (int)power(q, e) % p;

return result;

}

typedef struct arrayInside{

        int array[30][10];

    } arrayInside;              

arrayInside codesInside;            

struct arrayInside reverseInteger(){

int i, j, number;

for(i = 0; i < 30; ++i){
    j = 10;
    number = (aryConversion(q3[i], 3));
    do {
        codesInside.array[i][j-1] = number % 10;
        --j;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    while (number);
    codesInside.array[i][0] = 0;

};

return codesInside;
}

int chineseRemainder(int xq, int xp, int p, int q){

int tp;
int ceiling = (p*q-1)/2;

tp = ((int)(q * (powerMod(q, -1, p))*xp + p * powerMod(p, -1, q) * xq) % (p*q));
    if(tp > ceiling)
            tp-=p*q;

return tp;

}
```

Comment: This is *not* a complete example.

Comment: You know chineseRemainder() is the problem. So trace some example inputs and try to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Antti, what more would be helpful?

Comment: Provide the smallest example that is runnable, and produces unexpected output.

Comment: Thanks @merlin2011, I think I did that, now!

Comment: It would also be useful to show the expected output as well as actual output. This allows people to a) determine whether they've successfully reproduced the problem and b) determine whether they have solved the problem.

Comment: That seems reasonable, but given the arbitrariness of some of the values, anything other than a zero output is progress. I am limited in what I can make public, at this point, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is it just me, or is `chineseRemainder()` called with the same args everytime? None of the variables passed get changed in the loop...

Comment: Yeah, same values every time.

Comment: If the problem is with chineseRemainder then why did you say the problem is with printf?

Comment: You're both right -- it would be unnecessary to loop like this, if I were passing the same vbls each time. Those values for xp and xq are arbitrary, chosen for completeness and simplicity. The output is the same as it is when those vbls are given any int value.

Comment: So, if you take away the loop and just call it once with those arbitrary values, what is it supposed to return?

Comment: @immibis chineseRemainder is called by printf. It is printf that gives me zeros, even if it is doing that for some CR-related reason.

Comment: `printf` is just doing what you've asked it to do, print the return value of `chineseRemainder`.  That function is the problem and since you won't tell us what it's supposed to do you're kinda stuck.

Comment: Isn't power (q, -1) going to give a zero?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya great eye! It slipped my mind that integer arithmetic would, indeed, give 0 when raising anything to -1. I will need to fiddle with this stuff more, but I have a feeling this is exactly where I've gone wrong.

Comment: @LeftWingHegelian Actually it's not. Your function calls `chineseRemainder`, sees what value it returns, and then calls `printf` with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chineseRemainder actually returns 0 every time. Look at this -

```
((int)(q * (powerMod(q, -1, p))*xp + p * powerMod(p, -1, q) * xq) % (p*q));
```

powerMod(q, -1, p) is zero. So multiplying and adding it also going to give zero. Your function actually returns zero. There is nothing wrong. You probably need to check the logic or change the data types.